# How to find the rank of cofacts

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = (a_{ij}) ∈M_n(\mathbb{R})$; $n≥3$. Let $B = (b_{ij})$ be the matrix of its co-
factors, i.e. $b_{ij}$ is the cofactor of the entry $a_{ij}$ in $A$. What is the rank of $B$
when
a. the rank of $A$ is $n$?
b. the rank of $A$ is less than, or equal to, $n - 2$?
Already this problem is here but that question is wrong...Can anyone please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

- For a: if $A$ has rank $n$, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Definition) $AB^T = \det(A) I$.
- For b: recall that the rank of a matrix can be characterized in terms of the [determinants of its submatrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Alternative_definitions).